# Removing the blinking cursor when updating time in user form in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, forms, cursor

I have created a calendar using userform and put inside it a time tracker using label called `lblCurrentTime` is there some way to remove cursor blinking when using `Application.OnTime` function

The following code is perhaps responsible for cursor blinking i would like to remove this effect.

```
Option Explicit
    'Set global variable
    Dim UpdateTime As Double
    Dim LastUpdateTime As Double

Sub StartTimer()
    ' Set the initial time and schedule the first update
    UpdateTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    LastUpdateTime = Now
    Application.OnTime UpdateTime, "UpdateCurrentTime"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub UpdateCurrentTime()
    ' Update the label with the current time
    frmCalendar.lblCurrentTime.Caption = Format(Now(), "hh:mm AM/PM")

    ' Calculate the time until the next update
    LastUpdateTime = LastUpdateTime + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    UpdateTime = LastUpdateTime + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    ' Schedule the next update
    Application.OnTime UpdateTime, "UpdateCurrentTime"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub StopTimer()
    ' Clear any scheduled updates
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime UpdateTime, "UpdateCurrentTime", , False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems no issue on your Application.OnTime, Try Doevents after update the label.

Comment: cursor blinking? Where?

Comment: When loading the user form ( it's like a calendar ) and trying to add a date in the sheet i see my cursor blinking "the updatetime sub"  I can't fix the problem perhaps the built-in behavor of the application.ontime...

Comment: But where is the cursor when it is blinking ... in a cell in the sheet?, in a control in the UserForm? Please be specific. Also can you clarify what you mean by 'see my cursor', do you actually mean the caret (ie the vertical blinking line where you are typing) or do you mean the mouse pointer or do you mean you are actually seeing the text "the updatetime sub"? Note it is possible to add GIFs to your question if it would help to clarify these points.

Comment: I want to express my sincere appreciation for your assistance in helping me with this matter. It's been incredibly valuable.

To clarify my question further, when I mentioned "see my cursor," I was indeed referring to the cursor blinking within sheet when loading the userform that contains a label for showing and updating time using application.ontime + timevalue("00:00:01"):